# How do I count the number of matching tags using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, match

I'm using Python 3.7 and BeautifulSoup 4.  How do I find the number of matching elements when I do a findAll?  I have this

```
# Verify that we didn't see a no results message
no_images_msg = "No very similar images were found on Reddit."
elts = soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile("^.*" + no_images_msg + ".*$"))
if elts.count != 0:
    print("nothing found" + str(elts.count))
    print(str(elts))
    return json.dumps(results)
```

but the "elts.count != 0" clause always evaluates to true, even though through the print statement, I can see tehre are no elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite straightforward:

```
print (len(elts), 'elements matching')
```